# How to receive CFNotification in console application from Application in swift (OSX)

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, cfnotification

I am sending CFNotification from UIApplication to console application.
But i did not get the notification into console application.

here is my code.

```
// Posting notification from UIApplication 
// this code in objective-c

CFNotificationCenterRef distributedCenter;

distributedCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();

 CFMutableDictionaryRef info = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault,0,NULL,NULL);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(info, CFSTR("key"), CFSTR("value"));
    CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(distributedCenter,(__bridge CFStringRef)"notificationName",0,info,true);


// listening code in commandline application

let notifierNotificationReceiveName = "console-Notification"
let voidPtr = BridgeUtil.bridge(self)
let distributedCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter()

CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(distributedCenter, voidPtr, { (_, observer, name, message, userInfo ) -> Void in

        if (observer != nil){
            let thisView : NotificationHandler = BridgeUtil.bridge(observer!)
                var i = 1
                i = i+1
            }
        }
    }, "notificationName" as CFString, nil, .deliverImmediately)
```

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: hi @Willeke, I updated the code above which contain posting notification and listening notification

Comment: Is this a sandbox issue? Do you send the notification from iOS? How do you keep the command line app running? Is `self` still alive?